# Nonfinite Adverbial Clause

Tags: meaning, usage, conjunctions, clauses

For some unknown reason, these two sentences:

> 1a. The report describes the problems at the firm, ***blaming*** specific employees.
>   1b. The report describes the problems at the firm ***and it blames*** specific employees.

are close in meaning.

But these two sentences:

> 2a. He refused the offer, **knowing** that the offer was a trap.
>   2b. He refused the offer ***and he knew*** that the offer was a trap.

are not as close in meaning.  So, the two nonfinite adverbial clauses above have different functions and meanings?

Comment: It could be because you've arbitrarily chosen to use the same conjunction ***and*** in both your "rewrites". That particular conjunction is only one of several possibilities - your second rewrite would be better as *"He refused the offer **since** he knew that the offer was a trap"* (or you could get away with ***as***).

Comment: @FumbleFingers  How come the nonfinite adverbial clause in 1a could be replaced with a "*and....*" clause, but the nonfinite adverbial clause in 2a cannot?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Adverbial clauses like your two examples can be used in many ways, with many implied or explicit relationships between the "optional, parenthetical" clause and the statement it modifies. We could, for example, trivially extend your first statement to *"The report describes the problems at the firm **somewhat subjectively**"*, in which case it immediately becomes logical to replace ***and*** in your rewrite with ***since***. You seem to assume that ***and*** is inherently implied by the construction. It's not.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  An nonfinite adverbial clause is inherently ambiguous?

Comment: @meatie I'm no academic, but the reason that the meanings between the two rewrites are different is that sentence 2a directly implies that "he" refused the offer BECAUSE the offer was a trap. In 1a, the report describes the problem at the firm, and it also blames the employees, simultaneously. Therefore, the conjunction "and" becomes valid in that context, but it doesn't get the same meaning across in 2b.

Comment: @meatie: If it helps you to see it that way, yes. But I can't see it as a very useful approach. An adverbial clause obviously modifies something that's less specifically expressed elsewhere in the text, so in any given construction it must "mean" something. But the exact nature of the relationship between the "primary" text and the "parenthetical" element depends on the context. Loosely, you might think of rephrasing using ***and***, but this is a counterproductive approach if you allow yourself to suppose you can *always* do this.

Comment: ...you might be better replacing ***and*** with a period, so your "rewrite" leaves you with two separate sentences. Sometimes the two sentences can be sensibly "re-joined" using ***and***, but other times a different conjunction is more obviously suitable.

Comment: I think **2b** means *after refusing the offer, he knew it was a trap*.

Comment: @XPMai that is not right, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Participle clauses can express *cause, result, simultaneous actions, and consecutive actions* - the context will help you decide:

'He refused the offer, knowing it was a trap' - *cause* (because / since he knew)
'He refused the offer, forcing them to reconsider' - *result* (so they had to reconsider) 
'He refused the offer, smiling knowingly' - *simultaneous actions*
'He refused the offer, closing his case and leaving the room' - *consecutive actions*

Answer (score 0):

In option **2a,** the clause specifically answers the question **why**

*He refused the offer because he knew that the offer was a trap.*

In option **2b,** the causal logic is disjoint.